# ubuntu apt-get install all fiald?some errors with rsyslog

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
The user `syslog' is already a member of `adm'.
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 1: /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: /sbin/runlevel: not found
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript rsyslog, action "restart" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up ppp (2.4.5-5.1ubuntu2.2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service gdm has to be enabled to start service pppd-dns
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package ppp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up liblua5.2-0:amd64 (5.2.3-1) ...
Setting up librpmio3 (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up debugedit (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up librpm3 (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up librpmbuild3 (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up librpmsign1 (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up rpm-common (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up rpm2cpio (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up rpm (4.11.1-3ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rsyslog
 ppp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

this the error meesage.
At first, I just want to reinstall mysql.
when I `service mysql restart`,
ubuntu give me a `unkonw instance` error.
so, I reinstall it, then, I can't install it again. seems like apt-get install was not worked.

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get clean and sudo apt-get update` and then install your package. It will clear your existing lists and rebuild it.

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean and sudo apt-get update` This cammond returns nothing..

Comment: you can check `/var/log/apt/term.log` apt log file. Log file can help you with your issue.

Comment: also if there is some dependencies issue, run this command `apt-get install -f` first.

Answer (score 0):

**Stop the rsyslog first**

```
 sudo service rsyslog stop
 sudo systemctl stop rsyslog.service
 sudo systemctl disable rsyslog.service
```

**Then Try:**

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```